# Download email embedded images automatically

Tags: email, photos

Is there a way to set the email client to always download images in HTML messages?  I've looked all over and can not find any such setting.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible.

The choice of Microsoft not to support this is security. If you download html or images automatically the sender could see if you read the message for example by checking if you downloaded the image.

Hotmail supports whitelisting senders. would be great if you could also do this on your Windows Phone device but that's currently not possible

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no option to automatically do that for you. This to prevent data usage when you get email with big image files in it.

Comment: Not attachments, in the email body.  Even at 100k each my data plan would support 20,000 images a day.  An option would be good.

Comment: Its not mainly for data usage. Its mainly for security just like in outlook or other third party email clients. Sure, an option to whitelist an email or domain would have been good.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Windows 10 Mobile.

1. Open Outlook Mail.
2. Tap on the three dots at the bottom.
3. Go to Settings.
4. Click on Reading.
5. Select the account from drop down list or click the checkbox apply to all accounts.
6. Turn on "Automatically download images" under External content option.